# How can I access a jsp array in javascript function

Tags: jsp

How can I access a jsp array in javascript function with in a single jsp page?

```
String[] abc[]={"saab","volvo","bmw","Benz","Porsche","Jaguar"};
abc[0]="saab";
```

Comment: for (i=0;i<(document.getElementById("abc.length").value);i++)
 {
   alert("in loop");
   var sar=request.getParameter("abc[i]");
   var xyz = document.createElement("option");
      xyz.text = abc[i];
      xyz.value = abc[i];
      abc.add(xyz);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<%  
String[] abc={'saab',' volvo',"bmw","Benz","Porsche","Jaguar"};  
%> 

<script language="JavaScript">  

var jsArr = new Array();  
<%  
for (int i=0; i < abc.length; i++) {  
%>  
jsArr[<%= i %>] = '<%=abc[i] %>';   //Here is the latest update check it sravan .Put single quotes.
<%}%> 
</script>

  function myFunction()
  {
    var select = document.getElementById("dropDownId");

      for ( var i = 0; i < jsArr.length; i++ ){

      var option = document.createElement("option");
      // set the text that displays for the option
       option.innerHTML = status[i];
     // add the option to your select dropdown
       select.appendChild(option);

   }
```

Comment: give <select name="someName" id="demo"> in place of <select name id="demo">

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize it to json object first with for example FlexJson.

You could serialize java array to json array which should look like

```
[{item1, item2},{item},{item1,item2}]
```

with that method

```
String[] temp = ...
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("[");
for(int i = 0 ; i < temp.length ; i++){
    builder.append(temp[i]);
    if(i != temp.length - 1 ){
    builder.append(",");
}
}
builder.append("]");
String jsonArray = builder.toString();
```

and add this to your request;

then in your javascript use

```
var array = <%= request.getAttribute("temp")%>;
```

check if this is it with

```
console.log(array);
```

Comment: please can u give me an example

Answer (score 0):

print it to response literally and handle it via javascript.

behind-the-scene:
jsp-inline code is running on the server side. 
javasrcript code runs on browser..