# How to use jsp variable in javascript array?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Hi I have a jsp page where I have some variable. I want to access the variable in a javascript array. How can I get this?

**Demo.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <%
int i=1;
int j=2;
int k=3;
int l=4;
%> 

   </body>
</html>
```

I want to use these 4 variables in the javascript array and print them.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523379/how-can-i-access-a-jsp-array-in-javascript-function

Comment: i dont have an array in jsp only variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
<script language="JavaScript">  
    var Arr = new Array(); 
    Arr[0] = '<%=i %>';
    Arr[1] = '<%=j %>';
    Arr[2] = '<%=k %>';
    Arr[3] = '<%=l %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java script you have to use scriplet tag to use jsp data.

```
<%
  Integet a = i ; //here i is your jsp variable
%>
```

In order to make this work you should declare the variable before using it (as always):

```
<%
    String myVar="blabla";
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    foo();
    function foo() {
        var value = "<%=myVar%>";
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

Or :

```
var result = [];
result.push(<%i%>);
result.push(<%j%>);
result.push(<%k%>);
result.push(<%l%>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using JSTL.

1. set java variable to JSTL variable
2. Access it in Java script as

   var x='${jstl_varialbe_goes_here
   }';
   alert(x);